# How to make <input type="file"/> accept only .py and .json files

Tags: javascript, python, file, input, upload

I am trying to import only `.py` and `.json` file, and passing accept as
`text/x-python-script, application/json, text/x-python`

In windows OS, only `.json` files are able to get imported not the `python` file.

Comment: Try passing the file extension instead? `accept="application/json,.py"`

Comment: @IainShelvington . Yes. It is working. Please answer my solution. I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the filename extension for python files instead of the MIME type

```
<input type="file" accept="application/json,.py" />
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#unique_file_type_specifiers

Comment: how would I do this for pdf files? Hiten is asking

Comment: @Lazerlightning accept=".pdf" works